# What's the correct way of using `keep` function in `purrr` package

Tags: r, purrr

Suppose I have a list `x` as below:

```r
library(purrr)

set.seed(4152)
x <- rerun(5, a = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),1), b = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

```r
x

[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] "B"

[[1]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] "B"

[[2]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] "C"

[[3]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


[[4]]
[[4]]$a
[1] "C"

[[4]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


[[5]]
[[5]]$a
[1] "A"

[[5]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I would like to `keep` all elements in the list `x` that `$a %in% c("A","C")`, so I tried:

```r
x_sub <- x %>%
         keep(., "a" %in% c("A","C"))

Error: length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE
```

I think it is a nature way of coding based on my understanding of `keep` function. Why does it report error? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea but need to leverage `as_mapper()` to create a predicate function that will access the value that you want within the list. Instead of saying "a" in c("A", "C") we will say `x$a in c("A","C")` small difference but that makes it work.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(4152)
x <- rerun(5, a = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),1), b = c(1,2,3,4,5))

x_sub <- x %>%
  keep(., as_mapper(~.x$a %in% c("A","C")))

x_sub
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$a
#> [1] "C"
#> 
#> [[1]]$b
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$a
#> [1] "C"
#> 
#> [[2]]$b
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$a
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> [[3]]$b
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: Note that an explicit `as_mapper` or using `.` as the first argument are not necessary. `x %>% keep(~.x$a %in% c("A","C"))` will work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option in `base R`

```
Filter(function(y) y$a %in% c('A', 'C'), x)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$a
#[1] "C"

#[[1]]$b
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$a
#[1] "C"

#[[2]]$b
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5


#[[3]]
#[[3]]$a
#[1] "A"

#[[3]]$b
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a `purrr`, `plyr` alternative:

```
compact(plyr::llply(x,function(x) x[x$a %in% c("A","C")]))


[[1]]$a
[1] "C"

[[1]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] "C"

[[2]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] "A"

[[3]]$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```